# How to fix error submit app in windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, xap

I want upload one app in windows phone store but I have a problem

> this package is using an app name that hasn't been reserved for this app:"the reserved app name"

Answer (score 0):

**You Should Reserve Your App name Before Submitting Your App to Store.** If **App Name** you entered is **already reserved** or in use by another developer, you'll see an **error message and won't be able to reserve that name**. If you are unable to reserve a name for which you hold the trademark or other legal right, or you see another app in the Windows Store using that name, You can [contact Microsoft](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=233777).

Now If **another Developer has Reserved** that name you are submitting so You would be needed to **change your App name** that you are going to Submit in store and as well as in your WMAppManifest.xml file.

Comment: I am done with step 1 completed traces notice. Then move one step 
Review and Submit press the upload is complete and error it began moving through steps 1 to edit

Answer (score 0):

In the first category of your submission

[image]

Comment: i make sure that i use my reserved app name as the DisplayName in my app's manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Should it help others, the display name is found in a few places!

```
/Package.appmanifest
```

AND

```
Solution explorer/{Visual Studio project}/Properties/WMAppManifest.xml
```

I found I needed to modify the WMAppManifest.xml "Display Name" field before it worked but spent ages just modifying the Package.appmanifest "Display Name" and not getting anywhere.